# Mach-O binary: external undefined symbols not found after patching symtab

Tags: ios, c, ida, mach-o, dyld

I am trying to symbolicate reversed iOS binaries. So I started learning the Mach-O format [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachORuntime/Reference/reference.html) and wrote a basic program to test a simple example of adding one symbol to a stripped binary by hand (!):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int division(int a, int b);

int m;

int main(void)
{
    int i,j;

    printf("initializing i\n");
    i = 10;

    printf("initializing j\n");
    j=1;

    printf("i = %d, j = %d\n", i, j);
    m = division(i, j);

    printf("m = %d / %d = %d\n", i, j, m);

    return 0;
}

int division(int a, int b)
{
    return a / b;
}
```

What I did:

1. Compiled the source code to ARM above without any optimisation called 'helloworld'.
2. Stripped this 'helloworld' program and call it 'helloworld_stripped'.
3. Opened 'helloworld_stripped' in MachOView and hexfiend (to edit it).
4. Save As the 'helloworld_stripped' as 'helloworld_stripped2'
5. Modify the string table by adding '_division' **to the end of the string table**

[image: Modifying string table by adding division in red]

6. Added an entry in the symbol table of 'helloworld_stripped2' like so:

[image: Adding the division symbol in the symtab]

7. Modified the LC_SYMTAB and LC_DYNSYMTAB load commands to reflect new string table sizes, offsets etc. The following `otool -l` output reflects this ("* * * * *" is helloworld_stripped and '----' is helloworld_stripped2):
   [image: <code>otool -l</code> - load commands changed]
8. Then I open both 'helloworld_stripped' and 'helloworld_stripped2' in IDA pro and see this:

[image: Problem]

**Question:**

The patched executable 'helloworld_stripped2' is missing the printf function. Why is the printf function in the stripped executable and not in the patched executable? I did not change it in the symbol table and the position of printf in the string table is not changed.

Any advise is much appreciated!

**EDIT:** See answer below.

Comment: Ask as three questions instead of one

Answer (score 0):

Ok, basically, I found out the problem myself: I forgot to update the Indirect symbol table with the new symbol table entry values. When I updated it, IDA pro is able to show both _division and _printf.

[image]

The values circled correspond to the item index in the symbol table. Since the symbol table is updated the index of the indirect (such as printf) symbols change. So the dynamic symbol table have to be modified to reflect their new entry index. Hope it helps someone out there.